# Cordova - Content Security Policy removal - implications?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a web app that's wrapped with Cordova for Android and iOS.
I am having problems with the execution of Javascript code on Android devices, because of the Content Security Policy meta tag. I've tried several implementations, including to most relaxes ones that will allow basically anything to go through, but nothing worked.
So I just removed the CSP meta tag from my index.html to fix this issue. Now everything is ok on Android devices, but I wonder what are the implications of this.

**So what are the implications of completely removing the CSP meta tag? How can it affect my application?**

P.S. My app is basically a calculator for mathematical formulas that works both online and offline (Javascript/HTML 5)
My default meta tag was:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Also tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' foo.com">
```

and some other meta tags derived from these two.

Comment: so ... can anyone give me an opinion? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have the CSP working properly.  It will help against injection attacks and other issues. Here is a good guide on the CSP:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives

The examples you gave (if you wanted access to foo.com were not correct).  This would be a correct CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src http://*.foo.com https://*.foo.com 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

The default-src is used if no specific type src is given.  In the above example media files would be able to be loaded from any where over secure or insecure connections.  Your style sheets could only come from your own package and you can have styles applied inline.

Also you will want to use https unless you have a really good reason not too (in fact, Apple is starting to require it and will refuse apps if they load insecure content from anywhere without good explanation as to why).

Comment: my main problem is that I have scripts written inline that do not execute on Android. I didn't find a way to make the CSP accept inline scripts. In the documentation, it says "Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src". Tried this, still not working. I'll read more on your link.

Comment: I read your answer and the documentation and managed to get it working with the use of your wildcards. thx.